# Component not showing on Salesforce 1 app

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, lightning-app-builder

I'm creating a record page for opportunity from lightning app builder and drag and drop a custom lightning web component on that page and set the activation for desktop and mobile both.
But I'm able to see that component only on the desktop not on the Salesforce 1 app.
Please suggest me how can I show my component on Salesforce 1 app.

Answer (score 1):

Your visibility filter on the component is probably not set to have it show on the mobile app. It should be set to "Device not equal to desktop" to show on mobile.

You should read through the [Lightning App Builder Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_app_builder_considerations.htm) article.

Specifically this:

> ## Component Visibility Rules
>
> If a visibility filter assigns a component to “Device equals desktop,” the component appears on a page when viewed in Lightning Experience on a desktop and when viewed in a browser on an iPad.
>
> The Salesforce mobile app on an iPad uses the phone form factor. Salesforce viewed in a browser on an iPad uses the desktop form factor. These form factors affect components on record pages differently.
>
> - If the visibility filter is “Device not equal to desktop” or “Device equals phone,” the component appears on record pages in the Salesforce mobile app on both a phone and an iPad. It doesn’t appear on pages viewed in a browser on an iPad.
> - If the visibility filter is “Device not equal to phone,” the component appears on record pages in Lightning Experience on a desktop and on pages viewed in a browser on an iPad. It doesn’t appear in the Salesforce mobile app on a phone or an iPad.

Comment: Yes I tried to set the device factor equal to phone  for that component but from that I'm also unable to see that component on Salesforce 1 app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the .design file in your component contains the following in order for your component to be visible in the Salesforce mobile app:

```
<design:component label="YourComponentName">
    <design:supportedFormFactors>
        <design:supportedFormFactor type="Large"/>
        <design:supportedFormFactor type="Small"/>
    </design:supportedFormFactors>
</design:component>
```

Comment: Sorry I am having difficulty displaying the code in the format it should be in.  design:supportedFormFactors should be on new line.  <design:supportedFormFactor type="Small" /> should be on new line

Comment: Just select the code you want to format and hit the `{}` button in the editor (shortcut `CTRL` + `K`).